# Presenting Two ModalviewControllers one after the another in iPad

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, ipad

I am developing an ipad application and I have used a tabbar as a rootViewController, inside each tab I have splitviewControllers. Now, I am presenting a ModalView on click of a button this way

```
- (void)someFunction
{

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
           TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
            moveNote.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

            [appDelegate.splitViewController2 presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];
            test.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 350);//Dimensions of ModalView.
         }

}
```

I am presenting the ModalView through SplitviewController.

Now this opens up correctly. Now inside this I have a button, on click of which I want to dismiss this ModalView and present another ModalView. For this i have written the below code

```
- (void)closeTest
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                 completion:^{


                                     EditViewController *editViewController = [[EditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditViewController" bundle:nil];
                                     editViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

                                     [appDelegate.splitViewController2 presentModalViewController:editViewController animated:YES];
                                     editViewController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 350);//Dimensions of ModalView.
                                     editViewController.page = 3;              


                                     //Call delegate function.
                                 }];      
    }
}
```

But this doesnt work, and my application crashes.

What wrong I am doing here ?

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: not getting any log of crash

Comment: Have you debugged the completion block code. Is the controller created correctly? Do you call a delegate method after presenting?

Comment: my first ModalView is getting dismissed properly, and the control is coming inside the block, to present another ModalView and here it is not working

Comment: what happens if you present the second modal with animated:NO ?